# how to work with if define('DB_HOST','localhost')

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

in the past I have used smt like:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("xxx");
```

But now, I've noticed everybody started using smt like this:

```
if (!defined('DB_HOST')) define('DB_HOST','localhost');
if (!defined('DB_USER')) define('DB_USER','root');
if (!defined('DB_PASS')) define('DB_PASS','root');
if (!defined('DB_NAME')) define('DB_NAME','xxx');
```

What's different about their usage? For example echoing, filtering..

Thanks for help

Comment: This is done to make code more manageable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, none of them are wrong, it's your choice. I think the second alternative is more like a good practice. But my statement is valid only if you define it in one file and `require_once` in the others. Example:

`db_config.php`:

```
if (!defined('DB_HOST')) define('DB_HOST','localhost');
if (!defined('DB_USER')) define('DB_USER','root');
if (!defined('DB_PASS')) define('DB_PASS','root');
if (!defined('DB_NAME')) define('DB_NAME','xxx');
```

`query.php`:

```
require_once db_config.php;
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_NAME) or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxx");
```

But why? Imagine that you want to change your database name, user or password. If you have code `mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root")` every time you needed it, a change of plans will make you go through a lot of re-coding. But if you define them in one place as the second alternative does, you won't have to rewrite a lot of files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have connection in more than one place(poor design) With constants you would have one place where you can edit connection configuration without need to go through all code and find all the places where you opened connections.

So your connection code would look like:

```
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
```

Comment: If i put the variables in one file and do the include, doesn't it serves the same purpose?

Comment: Yes it does. The only difference, that you can not change constants on execution but vars can be changed so some people prefer constants. On another hand constants are pain to test, so I would go with just variables.